# Delete rows (customer) with a specific status value

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

I have a table named flightbooking. The table consists of fields including status marked with 'R' or 'C', Reserved and Cancelled.

[image: Flightbooking Table]

What I'm trying to figure out is to allow to delete records where status is 'C' but if the following row has status of 'R' it should not be deleted.

[EDIT]: I forgot to add that I need to delete a customer record from leadcustomer table.

So to summarize If CustomerID is 2 and status = 'C' The customer record can be deleted. 
Else if CustomerID is 3 and status = 'R' The customer record cannot be deleted.

Furthermore, by using

```
DELETE FROM leadcustomer
WHERE CustomerID = 2;
```

(This CustomerID record has status = 'C' so I should be able to delete it but foreign key violates the constraint.)

Comment: if you want to delete rows having 'c', use `delete from flightbooking where status ='C';`

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand your need, but this may be option for you: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-rowsecurity.html

Comment: My bad i did not write my requirements clearly enough, hopefully edit makes more sense on the solution Im looking for.

Comment: What is the error message you get? Also: please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Fixed the error, had to add ON DELETE CASCADE to my foreign key from flightbooking referenced to leadcustomers

Answer (score 0):

When you want to have inter-row dependencies, you must use window functions usually. The following might do the trick:

```
DELETE FROM flightbooking WHERE 
    flightbooking.id = (SELECT id FROM (
        SELECT id,status,lead(status) OVER (ORDER BY id) FROM flightbooking) a 
    WHERE a.status='C' AND a.lead <> 'R') ;
```

Comment: I have edited my post. Hopefully it makes more sense now. I have foreign key on leadcustomers table ALTER TABLE flightbooking ADD FOREIGN KEY(CustomerID) references leadcustomer(CustomerID);
Which prevents customers from being deleted. I need to be able to Delete customers where the status is C but R should not be deleted